# Delphi Dataset not in edit or insert mode

Tags: delphi

I have tried to search this but found nothing that helped me. I am trying to work on a school project where I need to add a record to an Access database but I am getting the error "dataset not in edit or insert mode.

```
sName := ledName.Text;
sUName := ledUserName.Text;
sPass := ledPassword.Text;
sEmail := ledEmail.Text;
sCell := ledPhone.Text;

dmUsers.tblUsers.ReadOnly := False;

dmUsers.tblUsers.Open;
dmUsers.tblUsers.Insert;

dmUsers.tblUsers.Last;
dmUsers.tblUsers['UserName'] := sUName;
dmUsers.tblUsers['Password'] := sPass;
dmUsers.tblUsers['Email'] := sEmail;
dmUsers.tblUsers['Cell Number'] := sCell;
dmUsers.tblUsers['Actual Name'] := sName;
dmUsers.tblUsers['Balance'] := 0;
dmUsers.tblUsers['Points'] := 0;

dmUsers.tblUsers['Present'] := False;

dmUsers.tblUsers.Post;
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Call `Edit` before editing dataset. Then just call `Append` (or `Insert` as you did) and remove your `Last` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call methods on the dataset that can change the active record (like `First`, `Last`, `Next` or `Locate`) the dataset will call [`CheckBrowseMode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.CheckBrowseMode), which will `Post` changes if modifed or `Cancel` the fresh record if not modifed. The result is the dataset being in `dsBrowse`, causing it to not accept editing.

So change your code to something like the following. I'll use [`Append`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Append), as your `Last` call suggests you wanted to have the new record at the end of the dataset.

```
sName := ledName.Text;
sUName := ledUserName.Text;
sPass := ledPassword.Text;
sEmail := ledEmail.Text;
sCell := ledPhone.Text;

dmUsers.tblUsers.ReadOnly := False;

dmUsers.tblUsers.Open;

dmUsers.tblUsers.Append;

dmUsers.tblUsers['UserName'] := sUName;
dmUsers.tblUsers['Password'] := sPass;
dmUsers.tblUsers['Email'] := sEmail;
dmUsers.tblUsers['Cell Number'] := sCell;
dmUsers.tblUsers['Actual Name'] := sName;
dmUsers.tblUsers['Balance'] := 0;
dmUsers.tblUsers['Points'] := 0;

dmUsers.tblUsers['Present'] := False;

dmUsers.tblUsers.Post;
```